# Xlib: pixels out of visibility

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ctypes, xlib

I am using `XGetImage` and `XGetPixel` to retrieve pixels from my monitors.
All work fine but pixels which are not visible on any monitor are setted by some sort of random values. A picture will explain better:

[image: Xlib: pixels out of visibility]

Monitor 1 is 1280x1024 and monitor 2 is 1080x1920. As you can see, there is a bottom-left square filled with old/random values. `XGetPixel` is so slow that I have in mind to set these pixels to black.

So my question: is there a  way to tell Xlib I do not want values from these pixels? Or I want it sets back to black or another value?
I was thinking of a bad management by the WM or the graphic card, but I have no idea how to deal with it, and if it is possible.

I am using Python 2 and 3 with ctypes, but the C code does the same thing.

The revelant code is used into my Python's module named [MSS](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/), file [mss/linux.py](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/blob/dev/mss/linux.py). Examples are clear on the presentation page.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to use Composite extension to be able to retrieve unmapped / obscured area of windows - see "When a windows contents are made available" part of [Composite tutorial](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/misc/x11-composite-tutorial/)